# How do I set one color red when tapped and not the other?

Tags: flutter, dart

As you can see, I've created two FlatButton widgets and set their states to confine with the code that every time one of them is clicked, it changes color to red. But I want only one of them to turn red for each time one of them is clicked. I'm not much of a genius at this stuff as I'm just a beginner, apologies!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Test'),
        ),
        body: MyStatefulApp(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyState createState() => MyState();
}

class MyState extends State<MyStatefulApp> {
  bool changeColor = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('TEST'),
            color: changeColor ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
              changeColor = !changeColor;
              },);
            },
          ),

          FlatButton(
            child: Text('TEST'),
            color: changeColor ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                changeColor = !changeColor;
              },);
            },),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

edit: I know that I could do that, but I'm planning on making numerous buttons in a GridView, and so I'd have to create hundreds of different variables, which is not ideal whatsoever. Any other solutions would be v appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new class for each button and then instantiate it on your Column, so each button will change only its own color.

```
class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyButtonState createState() => _MyButtonState();
  final String title;
  MyButton(this.title);
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  bool changeColor = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
        changeColor = !changeColor;
        },);
      },
      color: changeColor ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
      child: Text(widget.title)
    );
  }
}
```

Your column should look like this:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        MyButton('Button 1'),
        MyButton('Button 2'),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same variable name for both buttons. Create one variable for each button and update it on each `setState`.

It should look like this:

```
bool color1 = false;
bool color2 = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('TEST'),
            color: color1 ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                color1 = !color1;
              },);
            },
          ),

          FlatButton(
            child: Text('TEST'),
            color: color2 ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                color2 = !color2;
              },);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I know that I could do that, but I'm planning on making numerous buttons in a GridView, and so I'd have to create hundreds of different variables, which is not ideal whatsoever. Any other solutions would be v appreciated

Comment: In that case you can create a separated class for this widget and instantiate every button, so each button will only changes it's own color.

Comment: could you possibly give an example? I don't really follow, sorry

Comment: I'm adding another answer for that. Please edit your question and include what you said in your first comment.